# How to change script to use more UL select boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I found this code for ul select box. I need 3 different ul select boxes. So I made some changes but now is slide up only last "Year" select box. Is there a problem with "selected" tag?

ORIGINAL CODE:

```js
$("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').slideDown();
});

var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.slideUp();
});
```

```css
ul { 
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
ul li { padding: 5px 10px; z-index: 2; }
ul li:not(.init) { float: left; width: 130px; display: none; background: #ddd; }
ul li:not(.init):hover, ul li.selected:not(.init) { background: #09f; }
li.init { cursor: pointer; }

a#submit { z-index: 1; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="init">[SELECT]</li>
    <li data-value="value 1">Option 1</li>
    <li data-value="value 2">Option 2</li>
    <li data-value="value 3">Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

MY CODE:

```js
$(".day ul").on("click", ".active", function() {
    $(this).closest(".day ul").children('li:not(.active)').slideDown();
});

var allOptions = $(".day ul").children('li:not(.active)');
$(".day ul").on("click", "li:not(.active)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(".day ul").children('.active').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.slideUp();
});

$(".month ul").on("click", ".active", function() {
    $(this).closest(".month ul").children('li:not(.active)').slideDown();
});

var allOptions = $(".month ul").children('li:not(.active)');
$(".month ul").on("click", "li:not(.active)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(".month ul").children('.active').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.slideUp();
});

$(".year ul").on("click", ".active", function() {
    $(this).closest(".year ul").children('li:not(.active)').slideDown();
});

var allOptions = $(".year ul").children('li:not(.active)');
$(".year ul").on("click", "li:not(.active)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(".year ul").children('.active').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.slideUp();
});
```

```css
.day, .month, .year{
float:left;
width:100px;
display:block;
width:auto;
height: 34px;
}
.day ul, .month ul, .year ul {
  list-style-type:none;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 100px;
 }

.day ul li, .year ul li, .month ul li {
 float: left;
  width:100px;
 text-indent: 5px;
 height: 34px;
 line-height: 34px;
  border:1px solid #000;
 background: #fff;
}
.day ul li.active, .month ul li.active, .year ul li.active { 
}
.day ul li a, .month ul li a, .year ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
}
.day ul li:not(.active), .month ul li:not(.active), .year ul li:not(.active) {
 float: left;
 display: none;
}
.day ul li:not(.active):hover, .day ul li.selected:not(.active), .month ul li:not(.active):hover, .month ul li.selected:not(.active), .year ul li:not(.active):hover, .year ul li.selected:not(.active) {
 background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="day">
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Day</a></li>
<li><a href="#">01.08</a></li>
<li><a href="#">02.08</a></li>
<li><a href="#">03.08</a></li>
<li><a href="#">04.08</a></li>
<li><a href="#">05.08</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="month">
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Month</a></li>
<li><a href="#">01</a></li>
<li><a href="#">02</a></li>
<li><a href="#">03</a></li>
<li><a href="#">04</a></li>
<li><a href="#">05</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="year">
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Year</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2017</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2018</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2019</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2020</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to wrap up the original code with an iterator and your problem will be solved.

[I have create an example on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxodQM) with 3 UL tags, you can copy and paste the UL blocks to have the same code work on all UL tags

This is what your js code should look like.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("ul").each(function(){

    var $thisUL = $(this);
    $thisUL.on("click", ".init", function() {
        $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').slideDown();
    });

    var allOptions = $thisUL.children('li:not(.init)');
    $thisUL.on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
        allOptions.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $thisUL.children('.init').html($(this).html());
        allOptions.slideUp();
    });

  });

});
```